# What does frame, word, and bit mean on a FPGA

Tags: fpga

I know that frame, word, and bit is some sort of address.  But what does that mean exactly?  The reason I am asking is because I am trying to render an image of a FPGA based frame, word, and bit addresses and data related to those addresses.

Comment: which FPGA are you referring to? maybe this question will help you: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/249192/trouble-understanding-bitstream-frame-addressing

Comment: A frame is usually a group of words. A word is a group of bits. A bit is the basic unit of data, being either a 1 or a 0.

Answer (score 2):

The following definitions should be applicable:

- **Frame** - A group of words
- **Word** - A group of bits
- **bit** - The basic unit of any binary data - it can be either a 1 or a 0.

Typically a word would be the main unit of whatever data you are sending. For example if you are sending an RGB565 encoded image, one word would likely be a 16-bit value corresponding to a single pixel.

If sending data in chunks of multiple words, then you have a frame. In the case of images, a frame will be a single complete image. For example if you were processing a 320x240 image, 76800 pixels per frame. If each word of data was one pixel, then you would have 76800 words per frame.

Answer (score 1):

For an image of **m** x **n** pixels, it contains **mn** no. of pixels. *Pixel* is said to be the smallest constituent of an image. If we say the picture is a 24-bit image, it means one pixel of the image is represented by 24 bits, with R-G-B components' intensities represented by 8-bits each. So *Bit* is the smallest constituent of a pixel. It is the basic unit of a binary data , either 0 or 1. *Word* is a broad term. It depends on how you wanna define it. For eg. here you can represent one pixel by one word. It means 24 bits is one word in your current design. *Frame* constitutes all the pixels of the image. A *Frame Buffer* represents the entire image in the form of binary data. In the above example, it contains **mn** no. of pixels or words. i.e, **mn** x **24** no.of bits in total.